# Javascript : Scoping in Asynchronous Execution (using Callbacks)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I need some explanation to understand clearly what is happening here ;

We have these two code samples , the first one logs to the console **-1 five times** ,and that is because the for loop executes completely leaving i with the value –1, and only then do the callbacks start executing. The problem
is, when they execute, i already has the value –1.

The second sample logs the expected result which is a 5 to 1 countdown.The only difference between the two samples is that i is no longer declared in the scope of the `countdown()` function , *but why does that change the execution and how is the value of i being handled in the second sample?*

**Code Sample #1**

```
function countdown() {
 let i; // note we declare let outside of the for loop
 console.log("Countdown:");
   for(i=5; i>=0; i--) {
     setTimeout(function() {
     console.log(i===0 ? "GO!" : i);
     }, (5-i)*1000);
   }
 }
 countdown();
```

**Code Sample #2**

```
function countdown() {
console.log("Countdown:");
  for(let i=5; i>=0; i--) { // i is now block-scoped
   setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(i===0 ? "GO!" : i);
   }, (5-i)*1000);
 }
}
countdown();
```

Comment: The difference is 6 instances of `i` versus 1. The first bit of code does the same thing as `var i` would. It is scoped to the function, therefore, every reference to `i` within the function (including `i--`) is the same variable. In #2, however, it creates a new variable for each iteration of the loop with the value equal to whatever `i` is at the execution time of the iteration of the loop, *not* what `i` is when console.log() is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sample 1, the variable is declared just inside the function. You get a new `i` every time `countdown()` is called. Within `countdown()` the variable changes. By the time the timeout runs, `i` will be on its lowest value.

In sample 2, the variable is declared just inside the loop. You get a new `i` every time the loop goes around. This means you get a new `i` for every function you pass to `setTimeout`. The different timeouts are no longer sharing the same variable.

Answer (score -1):

The key difference is the use of the `let` keyword within the for loop.

In code sample #1, `i` is declared outside of the for loop. That means each access to `i` in each closure causes the same `i` to be dereferenced, because `i` is within the identical block scope of each closure, which is why we get `-1` each time.

In code sample #2, `i` is declared within the for loop, which means a *new* `i` is created for each execution. Each closure refers its own, exclusive block in the for loop which has a unique `i`. Thus, we get the expected 5 to 1 countdown.

For use of ES6 features like `let`, it can be handy to use the [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) REPL to determine how scoping rules are applied. The following simplified versions of code blocks #1 and #2:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(j); }, 1);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1);
}
```

...are compiled into:

```
"use strict";

for (var j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(j);
  }, 1);
}

var _loop = function _loop(i) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1);
};

for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  _loop(i);
}
```

Notice how, for code block #2, `i` gets copied into a distinct function scope using the `_loop` function where each closure refers to its own `i`.

[Check it out here.](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=GYewTgBAFANgpgFwgSwgXggBgNwogHggFZcBqU5ASggG8AoCCAZ0QBVkBbOEAVwSmA8AdgGMEyEEKjUaEEZKYh4AOhggA5lCq4AvgBoIARkrY6OunVCQoANwCGkAFbosuZ4RIRyjmQ2ZtObj4BYTEJKRk5BSU4VQ0oH10DY1NzOiA)